# Why aren't the total price updated when the first listing is created?

Tags: next.js

I am using Next.js and TypeScript.

1. When I update the first list, I want the prices to update as well, but that doesn't happen.

Please tell me the reason and solution.

2. Additionally, the word "Choose" does not appear in the box before making a selection.

I would really appreciate it if you could explain this issue as well.

```js
'use client'

import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface Option {
  key: number,
  value: string;
  label: string;
}

const OptionSelector: React.FC = () => {

  const options: Option[] = [
    { key: 1, value: 'tree', label: 'Tree'},
    { key: 2, value: 'cactus', label: 'Cactus'},
    { key: 3, value: 'moon', label: 'Moon'},
  ];

  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState<Option[]>([]);
  const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);

  const handleOptionChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const selectedValue = event.target.value;
    const selected = options.find((option) => option.value === selectedValue);

    if (selected && !selectedOptions.some((opt) => opt.value === selected.value)) {
      updateSelectedOptions((prevOptions) => [...prevOptions, selected]);
    }
    setTotalPrice(selectedOptions.length * 3200);
  };

  const handleCancelClick = (index: number) => {
    setSelectedOptions((prevOptions) => prevOptions.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  };

  const updateSelectedOptions = (callback: (prevOptions: Option[]) => Option[]) => {
    setSelectedOptions(callback);
  };

  return (
    <div className='p-10'>
      <select onChange={handleOptionChange}>
        <option value="" disabled hidden>
          Choose
        </option>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <div>
        <h3>Selected Option:</h3>
        <ul>
          {selectedOptions.map((option, index) => (
            <li key={option.value} className='flex flex-row'>
              {option.label}
              <button onClick={() => handleCancelClick(index)} className='mx-6'>Cancel</button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        {totalPrice}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default OptionSelector;
```

To solve the first problem, I created a separate button and displayed it on the console.
selectedOptions.length worked fine. However, the moment the code is entered into handleOptionChange, the price of the first list is not updated.

To solve the second problem, I couldn't think of an idea to solve it.

Comment: Originally I did it this way, 

'setTotalPrice(selectedOptions.length * 3200 );'

but now I did it this way

'setTotalPrice(selectedOptions.length * 3200 + 3200);'

 and the problem was solved. However, it does not seem to be a fundamental solution, so I would appreciate it if you could leave a comment on the solution.